# YAML MapSlice to preserve the sequence when marshall or unmarshall

Tags: go, yaml

I'm confused how to use YAML MapSlice data Structure. It's from here https://sourcegraph.com/go/gopkg.in/yaml.v2/-/MapSlice . I manage to unmarshall to a type of MapSlice but how to map it to my own struct

```
var data = `
id:
  id-jakut:
    en:
      name: North Jakarta City
      label: North Jakarta
    id:
      name: Kota Jakarta Utara
      label: Jakarta Utara
  id-jaksel:
    en:
      name: South Jakarta City
      label: South Jakarta
    id:
      name: Kota Jakarta Selatan
      label: Jakarta Selatan
tw:
  tw-tp:
    en:
      name: Taipei City
      label: Taipei
    zh-TW:
      name: 台北
      label: 台北市
  tw-ntp:
    en:
      name: New Taipei City
      label: New Taipei City
    zh-TW:
      name: 新北市
      label: 新北市
`

type cityLocale struct {
    Name  string `yaml:"name,flow"`
    Label string `yaml:"label,flow"`
}

type cityLocales map[string]cityLocale
type cities map[string]cityLocales
type countryCities map[string]cities

func main() {
    m := yaml.MapSlice{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("MAPSLICE==>%+v\n\n", m)     

    t := countryCities{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("NORMAL==>%+v\n", t["tw"])

}
```

Comment: You're asking how to preserve sequence, but your structure is unordered. What do you want to use the MapSlice for? Your `cities` structure doesn't work, because it a different structure than the YAML.

Comment: Okie i fixed the struct now, Yes how to preserve sequence. should i map m to t or any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your cities type, because you missed one map. If your cities are a map of map of strings your code works:

```
type cities map[string]map[string]cityLocales
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for not being clear. Yes i missed that part, but the real question is how can i preserve the ordering while unmarshaling,

Comment: maps are never ordered. So it is not possible to preserve the order of a map. The only thing you can do is to use a slice this has an order. If you are aware of the yaml definition you could define every object over a list, then you could unmarshal that structure into a slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the MapSlice to your own type. This involves type conversion. Especially for nested types like you have in your example.
I've given a very basic example in another answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777145/14108006).