# Go unmarshal yaml and preserve order

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

Let's say I have the following yaml file:

```
key1:
    - "Value1"
    - "Value2"
key2:
    - "Value3"
    - "Value4"
```

And I want to unmarshal that in Go. I can let Go decide what the scheme should look like and print it out.

```
m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
err := yaml.Unmarshal(yaml_file, &m)
fmt.Prinf(m)
```

This will print something like this:
`map[key1:[Value1 Value2] key2:[Value3 Value4]]`

But maps are unordered. The order is very important for me tho and I also don't want to loose the keys.

I can't just create a struct and try to unmarshal the yaml file to a slice of that struct...

```
type Element struct {
    Key   string
    Value interface{}
}

t := []Element{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal(yaml_file, &t)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
```

Will print `error: yaml: unmarshal errors: line 2: cannot unmarshal !!map into []Element`

There is no field tag to tell the yaml parser to fill the Key property with the yaml key.

Is there a different way than writing my own decoder?

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer right before I wanted to post the question.

The answer is **MapSlice**!
You need to import `yaml.v2` from `gopkg`. (As of writing this MapSlices don't seem to be implemented in yaml.v3 yet)

`MapSlices` implement exactly what I needed and are made of a number of `MapItem`s.

```
type MapItem struct {
    Key, Value interface{}
}
```

So now just unmarshal to a MapSlice. If you want to work with your own types you can always convert it but might need to do some typecasting.

```
m := yaml.MapSlice{}
yaml.Unmarshal(yaml_file, &m)

t := []Element{}
for _, item := range m {
    t = append(t, Element{item.Key.(string), item.Value})
}
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to upvote your answer. While it may work for you, I'm unsure if it's the best advice. You should make your encoding work for you. If you care about the order of fields then whatever is generating the yaml should use an array. Even if you can read unordered data in an ordered way, you can't always be sure that the unordered data was ever actually ordered to begin with, especially if the source of the yaml is from a 3rd party service. While you may be able to accurately say that the fields in your yaml are generated in an ordered fashion, that may not be true for future googlers.

Comment: I guess your answer does answer the question-as-written correctly. That type will read in fields in order. But assuming unordered data is ordered is a big red flag.