# Unmarshal a yaml file preserving the order of the keys in golang

Tags: go, serialization, yaml

I have a generic file, YAML that I want to unmarshal and maintain the order of the keys using golang. I have been doing a lot of research, and I have not found a solution that satisfies my requirement so far. Would it be possible to maintain the order of the keys when unmarshalling a YAML file that we do not have a struct defined for it? I also would like to maintain the spaces between each key when marshaling the data to a YAML file. Each YAML file I want to unmarshal can have different keys. An example of a YAML file that I want to unmarshal could be the following:

```
D: 20

B: 6

A: 30

D: 1
```

I tried using the MapSlice from the yaml.v2 package but it removes the blank lines between the keys when serializing the data to a yaml file. I also used viper package and it does not preserve the keys in order when deserializing the yaml file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it  removes the blank lines when serializing the data to a yaml file". When you unmarshal a yaml file to a data object empty lines in the yaml file are skipped. So, how should serializing the data object preserve empty lines? I don't think it is possible with yaml libraries I am aware of. Generally, MapSlice is your friend to preserve order of keys. Btw, did you see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777144/go-unmarshal-yaml-and-preserve-order

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of nodes in YAML:

- sequence node
- scalar node
- mapping node

As for `D: 20`, it's a mapping node, which means it is an unordered data structure for Key-Value mapping. To keep the order of keys and values, I suggest use `sequence node` for instead.

```
data:
  - D: 20
  - 
  - B: 6
  -
  - A: 30
  -
  - D: 1
```

Tested under Python 3.9 with PyYAML:

```
import yaml
doc='''data:
  - D: 20
  - 
  - B: 6
  -
  - A: 30
  -
  - D: 1'''
obj = yaml.safe_load(doc)
print(obj)
```

Result:

```
{'data': [{'D': 20}, None, {'B': 6}, None, {'A': 30}, None, {'D': 1}]}
```

**UPDATE: Go testing snippet**

Tested under Go 1.17 with `gopkg.in/yaml.v3`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type T map[string][]map[string]int

var payload = `data:
  - D: 20
  - 
  - B: 6
  -
  - A: 30
  -
  - D: 1`

func main() {
    t := T{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", t)
}
```

Result:

```
map[data:[map[D:20] map[] map[B:6] map[] map[A:30] map[] map[D:1]]]
```

NOTE: It produces an array of map with only one key, which guarantees its order.

Please see [YAML spec - ordered mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#example-ordered-mappings) for details.

Comment: My question is specifically on how to preserve the keys using golang and not using Python.

Comment: @triceras I updated a Go testing snippet.